# How to use document.getElementById().textContent for nested JSON data?

Tags: javascript, html, json, openweathermap

I am trying to access some nested data from OpenWeatherMap's API, here is an example of what I am using:

```
{
   "coord":{
      "lon":-74.46,
      "lat":40.55
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":800,
         "main":"Clear",
         "description":"clear sky",
         "icon":"01d"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{
      "temp":67.93,
      "feels_like":68.72,
      "temp_min":64.99,
      "temp_max":70,
      "pressure":1022,
      "humidity":77
   },
   "visibility":16093,
   "wind":{
      "speed":4.7,
      "deg":100
   },
   "clouds":{
      "all":1
   },
   "dt":1592439281,
   "sys":{
      "type":1,
      "id":5874,
      "country":"US",
      "sunrise":1592386010,
      "sunset":1592440257
   },
   "timezone":-14400,
   "id":0,
   "name":"Piscataway",
   "cod":200
}
```

Now inside of my function for obtaining the data from the API, I am trying to do as follows:

```
var weatherURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=08854,us&appid=(api key hidden for privacy)&units=imperial';
    async function getWeather() {
        const response = await fetch(weatherURL);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        const {name, temp} = data;
        document.getElementById('currentCity').textContent = name;
        document.getElementById('temp').textContent = data["main"]["temp"];
    }
```

The .textContent = name works just as I intend it to, but how would I correct the last line of my function so that I can access main.temp for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access that object like this `data.main.temp` and name like this `data.name`

Simplified jQuery code:

```
 var weatherURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=08854,us&appid=(api key hidden for privacy)&units=imperial';
        async function getWeather() {
            const response = await fetch(weatherURL);
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
            //Append Results
            $('#currentCity').html(data.name)
            $('#temp').html(data.main.temp)

        }
```

```js
var data = {
   "coord":{
      "lon":-74.46,
      "lat":40.55
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":800,
         "main":"Clear",
         "description":"clear sky",
         "icon":"01d"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{
      "temp":67.93,
      "feels_like":68.72,
      "temp_min":64.99,
      "temp_max":70,
      "pressure":1022,
      "humidity":77
   },
   "visibility":16093,
   "wind":{
      "speed":4.7,
      "deg":100
   },
   "clouds":{
      "all":1
   },
   "dt":1592439281,
   "sys":{
      "type":1,
      "id":5874,
      "country":"US",
      "sunrise":1592386010,
      "sunset":1592440257
   },
   "timezone":-14400,
   "id":0,
   "name":"Piscataway",
   "cod":200
}

//Append Results
$('#currentCity').html(data.name)
$('#temp').html(data.main.temp)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="weather_details">
  
</div>

<h3>Current Weather for <span id="currentCity"></span>
</h3><div class="weather_details">
   <p>Temperature: <span id="temp"></span>
   </p>  
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I have to use the script you provided? Because I need it to work constantly grabbing from the API.

Comment: We're getting closer--I am still gettting `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
    at getWeather` and my main goal is to use this in a <span> within a <p> tag.

Comment: @MatthewVandenberg Do you have an option to use jQuery or you just want to use javascript to do this ?

Comment: Whichever one is easier. Sorry I'm new to web programming.

Comment: @MatthewVandenberg okay sure. it would be easier for you to use jQuery and use `append()` i have updated my answer i will do  `span` for name and inside `p` for temperature.

Comment: Ok so I put all of that in getWeather(). Now what do I put in my html itself? I want it so I can do something like this: `<h3>Current Weather for <span id="currentCity"></span></h3>
 <div class="weather_details">
  <p>Temperature: <span id="temp"></span></p>
 </div>`

Comment: Looks like I figured it out and modified your jQuery to suit my needs. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MatthewVandenberg i have edited my answer above to what you need. Glad that i could help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
var weatherURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=08854,us&appid=(api key hidden for privacy)&units=imperial';
async function getWeather() {
    const response = await fetch(weatherURL);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    const {name, main: { temp }} = data; // Destructuring
    document.getElementById('currentCity').textContent = name;
    document.getElementById('temp').textContent = temp; // Same with name example above
}
```

Can you try this?
Not much changing your code.

Note: Also you can use `temp.toFixed(1)` for temperature as 67.9 not 67.93.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
    at getWeather`

Comment: This error sounds like there is problem with async fetch.
Because you already fetched data `const response = await fetch(weatherURL);` and waited. Then you parsed the data `const data = await response.json();` and waited.
data is already exists. There must be another issue i believe.

Comment: @MatthewVandenberg I just tried fetching and actually works. I recommend to check your asynchronous part of your code.

`const {name, main: { temp }} = data; // Destructuring
console.log("name", name);
console.log("temp", temp.toFixed(1));`

Output is: `name London
temp 292.4`